# How are you finding [something]?

Tags: expressions

I have read the expression "How are you finding [something] ?" (= What are you thinking of [something] ?) for the first time today. Is it used only/mostly in UK?

Comment: Waiter: how did you find your steak, sir? Diner: I just moved the peas and there it was!

Answer (score 1):

How are you finding  may be American usage

What are you  thinking  of / about is quite idiomatic in British English.

**What do you think about something** is used to talk about an opinion .

> What  are you thinking  of? ( idea)
>
> I am thinking  of going to  America.(idea)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that this usage of 'find' has a place in US English, judging by this entry in the Merriam-Webster (an American dictionary) entry:

> 3a: to discover by the intellect or the feelings : EXPERIENCE find
>   much pleasure in your company

Answer (score 0):

Although the usage is common in the UK ('I've always found him pleasant', for example), the online dictionaries I've looked at on and offline are strangely reticent about this precise meaning. (I forgot to try Merriam-Webster.)

However the OED mentions it specifically, as described [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393345/is-the-meaning-of-find-in-the-phrase-how-did-you-find-it-related-to-the-mean) on StackExchange when a similar question was asked two years ago.

The somewhat similar legal usage 'Do you find the accused guilty or not guilty?' is perhaps related.